# vertical-align css3. tried everything else

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align the `<a>`'s inside my navigation divs, and it is for some reason not working. I've already checked that there are no other styles overriding my code, and several combinations of positioning.

```
<div id="logodiv">
    <figure>
        <img id="logo" src="/images/Capture2.jpg" alt="logo" />
    </figure>
    <nav id="flexbox">
        <div class="menudiv"><a class="menua" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></div>
        <div class="menudiv"><a class="menua" href="events.html">Events</a></div>
        <div class="menudiv"><a class="menua" href="default.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="menudiv"><a class="menua" href="membership.html">Info</a></div>
        <div class="menudiv"><a class="menua" href="contactus.html">Contact</a></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#logodiv {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}

#flexbox{
    background-color:#f5b00e;
    float:right;
    width:65%;
    min-width:400px;
    height:30px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    display:inline;
}

.menudiv{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
}

.menua{
    line-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: font, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15pt;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Check it** http://jsfiddle.net/mKbLW/1/

Changed around some of your values. Had some unneeded css rules.

```
#logodiv {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}

#flexbox{
    background-color:#f5b00e;
    float:right;
    width:65%;
    min-width:400px;
    height:30px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    display:inline;
}

.menudiv{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

.menua {
    height:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    display:inline;
    font-family: font, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15pt;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you. for some reason it's still lining up the links to the top of the #flexbox<nav> container. They are still not vertically centered. Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove absolute positioning from flexbox and a margin-top instead.

Comment: Didn't work. I ended up just making the divs inside flexbox relative and the links absolute and positioned them about 10px from the bottom. My page is not responsive and none of the height/vertical values are percentages so I can't think of any downfalls to this. Can you? Thanks for your help Chris

Comment: Just that if you ever add or update you nav, you will have to go in an re-enter positioning values. Glad you found a solution though!